# How to best tune a Linux development machine?

Tags: linux, performance, development, tuning

How to best tune a Linux PC for development purposes?

Comment: I've found less tuning is required for Linux than for Windows, even when on the same hardware.

Comment: This belongs on Super User...

Comment: Depends on what kind of development you're talking about.

Answer (score 7):

Spend money on RAM first, disk second, and CPU speed third.  Use CVS or some other software version control system even if you're the only programmer.  Back up frequently.

Actually, spend money on a good monitor and keyboard first.

Comment: +1 for the keyboard argument. Also don't forget the mouse or a very good touchpad - except, if you do absolutely everything by keyboard. Just measure how long it takes to aim at the close button of a window with a cheap touchpad! (Ah, I see that this was an *old* question, but somebody just answered it :-)

Comment: use as SSD and watch those kernel compiles fly!

Answer (score 4):

- [Disable last access time on your filesystem](http://www.pctipsbox.com/speed-your-file-system-up-by-40/);

Answer (score 1):

Use noatime on non-important-data

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution doesn't do it already, consider to move /tmp to a ramdisk so temporary files would be created in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/10/performance-and-tuning.html

or

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/12/identifying-linux-bottlenecks.html

i feel 1st you need find out bottlenecks in server then you can use above links for tuning server!!!!!!!!